# jQuery grid binding takes too much time

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want 500 records from server and I use jQuery grid.

I use one WCF service to retrieve the data. I got data from the service in 10 sec. I can't change the query in WCF because its requirement of client and also lots of data.

When this data is bind into jQuery grid then it will take too much time and it gives error "stop the script because it takes too much time to run".

I search on Google for this error it says its browser error. So solve this error I have to make change into the registry.  do it and error is solved but the problem is I have to make change into the individual pc(client pc) which is not possible. My application in on web. So I can't tell all my client to make this fix,so I have to fix problem on server side.

I found one thing. jQuery grid used in my application is of 1.0.2.8 version and right now new version of jQuery grid is 1.0.3.8.

I download it and then also it give error, so what can be the possible solution?

My  query takes around 10 second for returning the result. So finally jQuery grid gives error stop the script it takes too much time to execute. What I do? I can't change my query logic.

Answer (score 0):

I have no specific experience with the jqGrid plug-in, but I can say that **A**JAX requests (even those that take a while) will not cause the slow script error because they are **A**synchronous.

jQuery Grid itself is probably taking too much time to add the data to the HTML page. Are you loading 10,000 records or a similarly large number? Try to cut down on the number of records you are showing on the page by limiting the length of your XML or JSON file accordingly.

If you can't cut down on the number of records to show on the page, perhaps you could modify your code (might have to modify jQuery Grid) to add only 100 records at a time (on a timer) to avoid the error. Then again, it still might not work if your input file is too large.

Comment: 10 seconds to return 500 results seems a bit slow, even for ajax - there must be some heafty data there..

Comment: Thanks for your reply and spend your important time for me.Instead of jQuery grid is there any other solution possible?Because the requirement is sure "500 records" so any how i have to display the 500 records.

Comment: How fast does your query run that gets the 500 records? I'm wondering if your query is the slow part?